# Why read() from a file always endwith a breakline

Tags: c, readfile

test.c

```
int main() {
    int fd = open("/test/aaa",O_RDONLY);
    char * str;
    int len;
    str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
    len = read(fd,str,100);
    close(fd);
    printf("%s\n",str);
    free(str);
    str = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

output is like:

```
$echo 300 > /test/aaa
$gcc test.c -o test
$./test
300

$
```

Why there's a line break output here? Is there a safe way to get ride of it ? Or did I use read() in a wrong way? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there's a newline in the file which you would see if you did a dump of it with something like:

```
od -xcb /test/aaa
```

The reason it's in the file is because you put it there: the default behaviour of `echo` is to write what you give it plus a newline character.

If you don't want the newline character, use:

```
echo -n 300 >/test/aaa
```

---

In addition, you haven't allocated enough space in your `malloc` to store anything other than a single character, you might want to try:

```
str = malloc (100);
```

You'll also noticed I *don't* cast the return value of `malloc` - it's a bad habit in C, which is perfectly capable of implicitly casting the `void *` returned into any other pointer. It can hide certain subtle errors if you explicitly cast.

It's also a given that `sizeof(char)` is *always* 1 in C so you don't need to multiply it by anything.

---

To be honest, if I want line-based file input, `read` wouldn't be my first choice. There are far better options like `fgets` for doing that sort of thing.

Answer (score 1):

The file you read in presumably already has a newline at the end. Remember, `read` reads as much as you tell it to.

When you use `printf`, you're requesting another newline to be added.

That's why you're getting two newlines.

Edit: You're also causing undefined behavior in several places in your program.

You're `malloc`ing space for 1 char but you're storing 100 bytes into it.

In addition, you're not null terminating the string which means `printf` will read characters until it encounters a null byte or it crashes. It could even keep reading chars to the end of the universe.

Answer (score 1):

You have *undefined behavior* in your code:

```
str = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
```

Here you only allocate *a single byte!* You then continue to read 100 bytes into this memory area. And you treat the allocated memory as a string, but you don't terminate the string properly, leading to yet another possible undefined behavior situation. And you don't even check for possible errors from your `read` or `malloc` calls.

And by the way, `sizeof(char)` *always* is `1`, and you should never cast the return of `malloc`.

Answer (score 0):

Because by default `echo` adds a newline at the end of the line. Which is why your file ends with a line break.

You can disable this by using `echo -n 300 > /test/aaa`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you put it there:

```
printf("%s\n",str);
```

Perhaps you meant this instead:

```
printf("%s",str);
```

Now you'll only get what the file contains. Of course, the file may contain a newline of its own at the end.

Comment: But there are actually 2 line breaks here (include one '\n' in printf). If no line breaks, output should be: `300$` ,right?

Answer (score 0):

```
$echo -n 300 > /test/aaa
```

-n will avoid the new line